# Create <body> innerHTML through Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting

Is it possible to add all the body elements through a javascript/jquery function which has to be called before the page load (onload) ??

Eg:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadBodyHtml()
{
var bodyHtml = "<div>Sample Div<br>";
bodyHtml += "<table><tbody><tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td></tr></tbody></table>";
bodyHtml += "</div>";
$(document.body).html(bodyHtml);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="LoadBodyHtml();"> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/qvru9/

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$("body")` and not `$(document.body)`:

```
$("body").html(bodyHtml);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geH5Y/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function LoadBodyHtml() {
      var bodyHtml = "<div>Sample Div<br>";
          bodyHtml += "<table><tbody><tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td></tr></tbody></table>";
          bodyHtml += "</div>";
      $(document.body).html(bodyHtml);
    })();
</script>
```

and remove this `onload="LoadBodyHtml();` inline event from body tag.

#### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6tm2/)

**What is an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression?**
It’s a function expression that gets invoked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

-->**$().ready()** function ll get executed during page load.

-->**$("").html(CONTENT);** to add elements in a Div..!

jquery Code:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $( "body" ).html("body elements");
 }
 </script>
```

Refer:

https://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/ready/